# Run multiple commands in network namespace

Tags: linux, bash, namespaces, ip, linux-namespaces

I'd like to run a series of concatenated bash commands in a network namespace in one single step, but it seems that `ip netns exec mynetns` only takes one bash command as argument.
For instance:

```
ip netns exec mynetns ip a
```

...works as expected.

```
ip netns exec mynetns "ip a ; ip a"
```

...returns `exec of "ip a" failed: No such file or directory`.

Clearly,

```
ip netns exec mynetns ip a ; ip a
```

... will return the interfaces in the network namespace and on the host machine.

Is there a way to make it work?

The [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) only talks about one command, which is not a very good sign...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

netns exec is running a command, not a bash command: it is executing a process with arguments itself.

That's OK, it just means you need to explicitly make bash the command. This should work:

```
ip netns exec mynetns bash -c "ip a ; ip a"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following ways in my code.

1: Use batching all shell commands following way.
Please take care of space/tab etc as batching is very sensitive to that.
PS: I am using multiple namespace isolation using unshare, that is optional.
Used that to give additional idea of various namespace isolation.

root@7fb1cd095b91:# ip netns exec $NSNAME unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /bin/bash -e <<START
readlink /proc/self
/bin/bash
readlink /proc/self
ls -lrt
START

2: Second using same commands in some script and call that script directly then batching bash commands inline.

root@7fb1cd095b91:#ip netns exec $NSNAME unshare -mpf --mount-proc --fork /bin/bash -c /tmp/start_ns.sh&